# Getting the guild id in an on_user_update event in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make an on_user_update event and to send the message I need to fetch the channel_id that is set as the log channel for the guild, which I sort by guild_id, but on_user_update has no guild attribute. So how would I achieve my goal?

Here's the code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_user_update(before, after):
    async with aiosqlite.connect('database.sqlite') as db: 
        async with db.execute("SELECT channel_id FROM logging WHERE guild_id = ?", ("answer goes here")) as cursor:
            result = await cursor.fetchone()
        if result is not None:
            channel = bot.get_channel(id=int(result[0]))
    
    if before.avatar != after.avatar: 
        av = discord.Embed()
        av = discord.Embed(title="**User Avatar Updated:**", color=7419530, description=f"After:")
        av.set_image(url = after.avatar_url)
        await channel.send(embed=av)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not be possible using only member. The only way would be able to do this is by getting a guild object and then using `after.id` to get a member object, or iterating through everything.

```py
guild = await bot.fetch_guild(GUILD_ID)
member = guild.get_member(after.id)
```

I did had to do something pretty jank when it came to this issue for my bot logs. Here's what I did:

```py
for guild in bot.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        if member.id == after.id:
            #do stuff
```

This iterates through all members the bot can see, and gets a member and a guild object when it finds the user in question. When the bot gets into a large amount of servers though, this will have to be updated so it can be scaled. In the meantime though, because my bot is in a small amount of servers, this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you call on_member_update before and after are Member Objects, this means that you can simply do this.

```
guild = after.guild
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I can think of getting the guild ID using the `on_user_update` event:

```
guild = client.get_guild(id_here).id
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, this might be the only way you can achieve this.